# Magento2 Theme Creation

Tags: magento2.3.4

I am going to work on Magento2(version 2.3.4), I want to create custom theme from scratch so, anyone tell me that how i can apply css,js,images,icons,fonts as well as what is the folder structure of theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css,js,fonts,images can available in web directory of current theme.